# How to remove a character within a certain identifiable string using perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

First I need to identify a particular string that looks like this:

```
my $removeU8374 = 'test A dkdkd荴kdklsl skldsls荴lksdkdk skdkd荴kdkls';
```

I then want to remove a particular character (U+8374) from the string.

So far I've tried this:

```
$removeU8374 = ~ s/^test A (.*[^\N U+8374])//g;
```

But it's not working...

Comment: There cannot be a space in the middle of `=~`. It's one operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a character with regular expression, you can capture the part before and after it and put these parts together. According to [ESCAPE SEQUENCES](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#ESCAPE-SEQUENCES) a Unicode character is matched with `\N{U+8374}`

```
$removeU8374 =~ s/^(test A .*)\N{U+8374}(.*)/$1$2/;
```

This captures `test A ...` and everything after `U+8374` and concatenates both together.

Comment: Better: `$removeU8374 =~ s/^(test A .*)\N{U+8374}/$1/;`

Comment: Even better: `$removeU8374 =~ s/^test A .*\K\N{U+8374}//;`

Answer (score 3):

All you need is

```
$removeU8374 =~ s/\N{U+8374}//g;
```

or

```
$removeU8374 =~ s/\x{8374}//g;
```

If that doesn't work, it's because `$removeU8374` doesn't actually contain U+8374. You can see what it actually contains using

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Dumper($removeU8374));
```

Demonstration:

```
use utf8;                               # Source file is encoded using UTF-8
use encode ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal expects UTF-8.

my $removeU8374 = "test A dkdkd荴kdklsl skldsls荴lksdkdk skdkd荴kdkls";
$removeU8374 =~ s/\N{U+8374}//g;
print("$removeU8374\n");
```